# Conditional copy element of one column and apply to all satisfied rows Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is very very simple, not sure what I am missing out.
I have to copy 'code_num' of 'primary_fruit' and apply it to all reference rows based on 'fruit_list'.
if df[fruit] is not present in fruit_list then copy self 'code_num'

```
fruit_list= ["apple","banana","cherry"]
primary_fruit = 'banana'

print(df)

Store code_num     fruits
A     101          apple  
A     102          cherry 
A     103          cherry 
A     104          banana 
A     105          cherry 
A     106          rambo  
B     201          cherry
B     202          banana
B     203          toy
```

Expected Dataframe:

```
Store code_num    fruits      reference
A     101          apple       104
A     102          cherry      104
A     103          cherry      104
A     104          banana      104
A     105          cherry      104
A     106          rambo       106
B     201          cherry      202
B     202          banana      202
B     203          toy         203
```

Below code I have written but giving incorrect output:

```
s = df['fruits'].isin(fruit_list)
df.loc[s,'reference'] = df.groupby([s,'Store'])['code_num'].transform('max')
```

Comment: What with `primary_fruit`, you arent using it anywhere like you have described

Comment: What output does it give? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with

```
df['refer']=df['code_num']


df.loc[df.fruits.isin(fruit_list),'refer']=df.loc[df.fruits.eq(primary_fruit),'refer'].iloc[0]

df
Out[26]: 
  Store  code_num  fruits  refer
0     A       101   apple    104
1     A       102  cherry    104
2     A       103  cherry    104
3     A       104  banana    104
4     A       105  cherry    104
5     A       106   rambo    106
```

---

Update we need `Categorical` and re-order the dataframe than do `transform`

```
d=dict.fromkeys( fruit_list, primary_fruit)
newdf = df.iloc[pd.Categorical(df.fruits, ["banana","apple","cherry"]).argsort()]
df['ref']=newdf.groupby([newdf.Store, newdf.fruits.replace(d) ])['code_num'].transform('first')
df
Out[46]: 
  Store  code_num  fruits  ref
0     A       101   apple  104
1     A       102  cherry  104
2     A       103  cherry  104
3     A       104  banana  104
4     A       105  cherry  104
5     A       106   rambo  106
6     B       201  cherry  202
7     B       202  banana  202
8     B       203     toy  203
```

Comment: But there will be other stores as well and this approach will break the Stores boundaries. Probably will have to use group by clause

Comment: @nealkaps can you elaborate what you mean by "store", how could answer-er assume everything you need to cater.

Comment: @A.B Thanks for highlighting the issue, I have added more example with another Store.

Comment: @nealkaps check the update :-) hope you enjoy the answer and please make your question more clear next time. Good question BTW

Comment: @BEN_YO elegant answer! I was curious is there a way, to not hard code the values ['banana', 'apple', 'cherry'] and instead pass the variable, I did try passing the variable but the output is again messed  :(

Comment: @BEN_YO I was talking about ```["banana","apple","cherry"]).argsort()```, But I found a way around to handle that. Thanks as always man :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
primary_code = df.query('fruits == @primary_fruit')['code_num'].values[0]

df['reference'] = df['code_num'].where(~df['fruits'].isin(fruit_list), primary_code)
```

Update to include `Store`

```
primary_codes = (
    df
    .set_index('Store')
    .query('fruits == @primary_fruit')['code_num']
    .to_dict()
    )

df['reference'] = df.apply(lambda x: 
                     x['code_num'] 
                     if x['fruits'] not in fruit_list 
                     else primary_codes.get(x['Store']),
                   axis=1)
```

Comment: Wouldnt it give error of mismatching length between  `df['reference'] ` and `df.where(~df['fruits'].isin(fruit_list), primary_code)`

Comment: You're right. It must be a Series, not a DataFrame. Correction done, thanks!